# how to change user's TimeZone

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server-2012

Need to change domain user TimeZone.

A Windows Service is running under X user's context, at runtime the Application takes X-user's TimeZone and generates "messages" with a different DateTime to local machine DateTime. need to run Windows Service as this user, so, Need to change this specific user's TimeZone to match machine's DateTime.

Setting / Time and Languages / Time zone was changed but it only aplies to local machine level, this is assumed by the following test (On a different server, different domain):
1.- Log on as A1 to server
2.- Change `Settings / Time and Languages / Time zone` to `TZ1` (Hour on taskbar changed)
3.- Log on as B1, check `Time zone` property and this is `TZ1`

Maybe on Active Directory?

DateTime on "messages" can't be changed manually, those messages are generated on a third party dll.

Comment: "it only applies to the machine level." - What do you mean by this exactly?  Edit your question to provide the relevant information necessary to answer your question.  If you know the TimeZone of the message, just change the TimeZone of the machine, and configure your domain in such a way the TimeZone cannot be changed by the user.  If you don't actually know the TimeZone of the message, then it will be difficult, to change the TimeZone so it matches.

Comment: Please take the time to properly format the information.  Any information contained in a comment likely won't be considered in any answer that is submitted or will simply be overlooked.